# How to find lost files and lost free space on flash card

Tags: finder, spotlight, trash, flash-memory

Flash card is indicated mostly filled

[image]

Simultaneously, I can't find any files of appropriate size

```
% sudo du -ah   
128K    ./.fseventsd/fseventsd-uuid
256K    ./.fseventsd
340M    ./NORMAL/2022-08-05-19-08-17.MOV
1.8M    ./NORMAL/2022-08-05-12-01-48.JPG
342M    ./NORMAL
du: ./.Spotlight-V100: Operation not permitted
460M    ./EVENT/2022-08-05-16-56-54.MOV
460M    ./EVENT
du: ./.Trashes: Operation not permitted
803M    .
```

What are these files (`.Spotlight-V100` and `.Trashes`) which are not accessible? Why aren't they accessible even with `sudo`? How to access them?

Answer (score 0):

As the names suggest, `.Spotlight-V100` is a Spotlight index for the contents, and `.Trashes` is the Trash folder for the volume.

If you empty the Trash in the Finder, then that should clear the contents of the `.Trashes` folder.

The Spotlight folder is unlikely to be massive. I have one that's 500Mb on a 2 TB drive (that's c. 50% full).

FWIW, I can access the Spotlight folder on my external drives, but the `.Trashes` denies me, as it has no read attributes.

```
    Ben@Bens-Mini Media City % ls -la
total 24
drwxrwxr-x@ 18 Ben   staff    576 19 May 19:41 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel    160  7 Aug 17:53 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 Ben   staff  10244 29 Nov  2021 .DS_Store
d--x--x--x  10 Ben   staff    320  6 Aug 09:47 .DocumentRevisions-V100
drwx------   5 Ben   staff    160 30 May  2020 .Spotlight-V100
d-wx--x--t   5 Ben   staff    160 26 Sep  2020 .TemporaryItems
d-wx--x--t   3 Ben   staff     96 29 Oct  2021 .Trashes
drwx------  26 Ben   staff    832  6 Aug 09:46 .fseventsd
```